# ruby self.inherited alias_method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, alias-method

```
class Base
  def sam
    "I m the base"
  end

  def self.inherited(base)
    alias_method :old_sam, :sam
    base.class_eval do
      def sam
        old_sam 
        p "Inside inherited"
      end
    end
    super
  end
end

class Derived < Base
  def sam
   p "Inside Derived"
  end
end
```

when Derived.new.sam => "Inside Derived"

But I expect

"Inside Derived"

"Inside inherited"

New to ruby. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have simply overriden the defined by `base.class_eval` method `sam` in `Derived`.

If you remove the method `sam` from `Derived`:

```
class Derived < Base
end
```

You will get:

```
#=> "Inside inherited"
#=> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
```

The latter is because you are passing an argument to `old_sam` method, which does not take it:

```
old_sam p "Inside inherited"
```

> But I expect
>
> "Inside Derived"
>
> "Inside inherited"

This is not possible with your set up, because what you do is first defining an instance method `sam` in `class_eval` block for all descending classes, but later just overriding in.

Comment: Thanks Andrey. The method old_sam doesn't  accept any arguments, and the code is changed accordingly now. Sorry for that.

Comment: @Raj I answered your question, editing it down the way not a good choice and it does not make sense now since it does not change the answer given.